# Can't get values out of allHeaderFields dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, http-headers

For some reason I'm not able to get the right values from the key in a dictionary that I need in swift. This works in objective c..

```
var newRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: navigationAction.request.URL!)
newRequest.HTTPMethod = "HEAD"
var response: NSURLResponse?
var filename: AnyObject?
var filetype: AnyObject?
NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(newRequest, returningResponse: &response, error: nil)
if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
    let allHeaders = httpResponse.allHeaderFields
    filename = allHeaders["sfn-Document-Filename"]
    let typeString: AnyObject? = allHeaders["Content-Type"]
    let typeArray: Array = typeString!.componentsSeparatedByString("/")
    filetype = typeArray[1]
}
```

This dictionary object looks like this `allHeaders  [NSObject : AnyObject]  6 key/value pairs`.

[image: Screenshot of the Dictionary keys/values]

Here's the objective c that still works.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[request URL]];
[newRequest setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:newRequest returningResponse:&response error: NULL];
if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [response allHeaderFields];
    filename = [[response allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"sfn-Document-Filename"];
    NSString *typeString = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Content-Type"];
    NSArray *typeArray = [typeString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    filetype = [typeArray objectAtIndex:1];
}
```

It doesn't need to be done the same way as the Obj-C, it's just this worked and it seemed like a good place to start.

The value I'm getting for filename is `filename = (AnyObject?) Some`

I've tried changing it to:

```
var filename: String?
filename = allHeaders["sfn-Document-Filename"] as? String
```

But now I get a nil String and `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)`

Comment: "I'm not able to get the right values from the key in a dictionary": does it mean you get wrong values? Or no values at all?

Comment: @EricD. I get `filename = (AnyObject?) Some`

Comment: Just a guess, then: try `filename = allHeaders["sfn-Document-Filename"] as! String` and see if you get a proper String (explanation: I think Swift doesn't know the type of the object you try to fetch). EDIT: even better, give your objects the right type from the beginning: `var filename: String?`

Comment: @EricD. Now I get a nil string.

Comment: Weird. You should put a breakpoint on `let typeArray: Array = ...` then inspect the actual value of `allHeaders["sfn-Document-Filename"]` in the debugger, because given what I see in your screenshot, you shouldn't get nil for your string.

Comment: @EricD. ah it's nil because i'm getting `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)` not sure how I missed that before..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this all was happening is because the value of the key in the dictionary appears to be an `NSString` and it can't find it with a `String` (I thought they were supposed to be interchangeable though?).

Either way. Doing this worked:

```
var newRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: request.URL!)
newRequest.HTTPMethod = "HEAD"
var response: NSURLResponse?
NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(newRequest, returningResponse: &response, error: nil)
var filename: NSString?
var filetype: String?
if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
    let headerString = "sfn-Document-Filename"
    let headerNSString: NSString = (headerString as NSString)
    let filetypeString = "Content-Type"
    let filetypeNSString: NSString = (filetypeString as NSString)

    var allHeaders = httpResponse.allHeaderFields

    filename = allHeaders[headerNSString] as? NSString

    let typeString = allHeaders[filetypeNSString] as? NSString
    let typeArray = typeString!.componentsSeparatedByString("/")
    filetype = typeArray[1]
}
```

Now I just need to figure out why `componentsSeparatedByString` isn't working...